# Python: Sort 2d ndarray and return a list of index in tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I try iterate over values of a 2d ndarray and get the index as well.
Therefor I tried to sort the 2d ndarray. Also tried different things with (arg-)sorting parameters of numpy.

```py
import numpy
arr = numpy.array([[2,11,4], [33,9,5], [3,21,123]])
print(arr.argsort(axis=None)
```

This returns:

```py
array([0, 6, 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 3, 8])
```

But I want to return a list like this where each list element contains the 2-dimensional index like this:

```
[(0,0), (2,0), (0,2), (1,2), (1,1), (0,1), (2,1), (1,0), (2,2)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numpy's [`unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html), we can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[2,11,4], [33,9,5], [3,21,123]])
ix, jx = np.unravel_index(arr.argsort(axis=None), arr.shape)
print(list(zip(ix,jx)))
```

Which outputs

```
[(0, 0), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
```

for this example, as requested.

Comment: Works perfectly for me